# How can I Repeat Excel SQL query on separate cell values

Tags: sql, excel

What I am trying to do is create an SQL query to be executed on each row separately, taking a cell data as a criteria. ie. I have an SQL query that fetches a record based on a Student ID. I wish to be able to paste a set of Student IDs into a column A and have each student record be displayed on the respective row.

Table Student

```
STUDENT_ID      FIRST_NAME     LAST_NAME        DOB
A001            John           Little          19701020
A002            Tim            Henry           19690105
A003            Alex           Dalton          19730312
A004            Chris          Lee             19720822
A005            Susan          Johnson         19710723
```

Query in Excel Macro:-

```
select * from Table.Student where Student_Id = 'CellA1'
```

Output in Excel Sheet1:-

```
A001            John           Little          19701020
```

I am fairly new to SQL and databases so I'm finding this a bit of a trouble. I managed to use one cell value to fetch one record, so it occured to me to create a separate SQL query for each row, but that seems a bit ridiculous...

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you omit the condition? I.e. just `select * from Table.Student`, without `where` – would it solve the problem?

Comment: It will extract the entire database & that's not what I wish to do. I need to extract the records based on the data in excel column.

Answer (score 0):

Just so I understand your question, are you looking at generating queries from data in excel columns?

Once you have your query will you be running it in a SQL management studio (or other) program?

Comment: Correct, I'm generating queries from data in excel columns & once I hv it, i'll execute the query thru excel macro.

Comment: @Bob: How does your macro get fired?

Comment: I'll insert a SQL query, like this:- select * from Table.Student where Student_Id = 'CellA1'

Comment: @Bob: No, I mean, when does it fire? What causes it to run? Do you call it manually (by a hot-key, for example) or is it envoked automatically upon inserting a value in the cell or something? Anyway, is it possible to elaborate your macro so it would run through a column of cells in a sort of loop and generate/run the same query for every cell according to its value? A bit more background, and well illustrated too, might help us to see where the actual problem is and how it could be solved.

Comment: Well, user will need to insert the ID in column A1, A2, A3... etc. Once done, user will just need to press a button (with assigned macro). Problem is the ID list in column A is not fixed ie. it may be one or more. The macro will run through column A with the same query.

Comment: @Bob: Alright, so your macro does run through a series of cells then. I can see that it would probably be better in terms of both design and performance to have your macros run *one* query for all the cells, and then put each data row accordingly in a separate sheet row. I have to admit that this particular problem is beyond me. So if I were you I would probably have stuck initially with running an individual query for every cell in question, dealing each time with the result accordingly. If you have no solution so far, it is better than nothing. A better one may become apparent with time.